¿Qué son los operadores << y >> y qué hacen?
He visto estos operadores << y >> en bloques de código de C++ y C#, pero no consigo entenderlos.
He probado este código en C++:
int x = 5;
int y = x << 1; // y es 10
int z = x << 2; // z es 20

Y no entiendo por qué y es 10 y z es 20.
¿Por qué sucede esto?

Recuerda revisar [ask]

@Jorgesys El objetivo de esta pregunta auto respondida es el mismo que otras preguntas que he realizado con la misma dinámica. Aportar contenido al sitio. Si fueses tan amable en señalarme que está mal con mi pregunta o respuesta, me sería de gran ayuda.

Este tipo de preguntas se pueden realizar en [chat]. Si se tiene duda sobre estos operadores, simplemente puedes revisarlo en la documentación https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/

Los operadores citados en la pregunta << y >> se llaman operadores de desplazamiento de bits, y tienen comportamientos similares en C++ y C#, además de otros lenguajes donde son soportados, como C o Java.

En el caso de C++, cuando se emplea cout << ... no se están desplazando bits a la izquierda, ya que en este contexto cout es una instancia de la clase ostream que sobrecarga el operador << para que sea un operador de inserción de flujo, no de desplazamiento.
Entonces, si por ejemplo tenemos cout << "Welcome to GFG" lo que sucede es que estamos insertando el valor "Welcome to GFG" al flujo de salida ostream que es representado por cout.
Agradezco a Candid Moe y a Yussef por señalarlo.


El operador << es el operador de desplazamiento a la izquierda. Esto quiere decir, que desplaza los bits hacia la izquierda un número de veces determinado y rellena con ceros a la derecha.
Por ejemplo, si tenemos este código en C++:
int x = 5;      // 5 en binario es 00000101
int y = x << 1; // y es 10, que en binario es 00001010
int z = x << 2; // z es 20, que en binario es 00010100

Ahora, vamos a desglosar el ejemplo de código anterior, para entender lo que está pasando:
Primero, asignamos el valor 5 a una variable de tipo entero. Recordando que 5 en binario es 00001010.
int x = 5;

A continuación, empleamos el operador << de desplazamiento de bits a la izquierda.
int y = x << 1;

Lo que sucede aquí, es que estamos desplazando 1 posiciones a la izquierda los bits del valor 5. Si fuese x << 2 estaríamos desplazando 2 posiciones a la izquierda los bits de 5, y así sucesivamente.
Que desplaza 1 posiciones a la izquierda los bits del valor 5 que es lo que reside en la variable x. Sabiendo que 5 en binario es 00000101, al aplicar el desplazamiento una posición a la izquierda, nos deja con 00001010.
Vemos que se insertó un cero al final y que 101 está una posición más cerca de la izquierda.
00001010 es 10 en decimal.
Lo mismo sucede con:
int z = x << 2;

Donde estamos desplazando los bits dos posiciones a la izquierda. Entonces, el valor 5 que es lo que contiene la variable x que en binario es 00000101 pasa a ser 20 en decimal, que en binario es 00010100.
Aquí vemos que ahora 101 está dos posiciones más cerca de la izquierda que ahora tenemos dos ceros a la derecha.

El operador >> de desplazamiento a la derecha es similar al anterior. Este desplaza los bits a la derecha con una diferencia importante, que en vez de rellenar con ceros a la izquierda, rellena con el bit de signo.
El bit de signo para números negativos (con signo) es 1, y para números positivos (sin signo) es 0.
Entonces:
int x = 5;      // 5 en binario es 00000101
int y = x >> 1; // y es 2, que en binario es 00000010
int z = x >> 2; // z es 1, que en binario es 00000001

Y si x contiene un valor negativo (con signo):
Cuando se desplaza un número negativo a la derecha, se rellena con 1 a la izquierda para preservar el signo negativo.
int x = -5;     // -5 en complemento a 2 es 11111011
int y = x >> 1; // y es -3, que en binario es 11111101
int z = x >> 2; // z es -2, que en binario es 11111110


¿Que es eso de en complemento a 2? 
De acuerdo con esta entrada en Wikipedia: El complemento a 2 es una forma de representar números negativos en el sistema binario. Permite representar tanto números positivos como negativos utilizando el mismo número de bits, con una forma sistemática de manejar el signo y las operaciones aritméticas.


Como curiosidad: Nótese como en cada desplazamiento a la izquierda, es valor se multiplica por 2. x = 5, y = 10 y z = 20. Y en cada desplazamiento a la derecha el valor se divide entre 2. x = 5, y = 2 y z = 1.
Es un efecto directo de la representación posicional de los números en binario. En binario, cada posición (bit) representa una potencia de 2:
Posiciones: 128  64  32  16  8   4   2   1
Ejemplo 5:   0    0   0   0   0   1   0   1
             2^7 2^6 2^5 2^4 2^3 2^2 2^1 2^0

Entonces, cuando desplazas a la izquierda (<<), equivale a:
5 (00000101) << 1 = 10 (00001010)

O lo que es lo mismo:
5 * 2^1 = 10

Y si desplazas a la derecha (>>), equivale a:
5 (00000101) >> 1 = 2 (00000010)

O lo que es lo mismo:
5 / 2^1 = 2


¿Y qué pasa con cout << "Welcome to GFG";?

@CandidMoe En C++, si hablamos de cout, el operador << no es de desplazamiento, sino de inserción de flujo. << está sobrecargado en la clase ostream para la inserción de datos en el flujo de salida y cout es una instancia de esta clase.

@HéctorM. Creo que lo que intenta señalarte Candid, es que dado que has puesto la etiqueta C++ y que en ese lenguaje los operadores << y >> tienen otro uso que quizás es más habitual que el desplazamiento de bits, quizás sería bueno al menos mencionarlo en la respuesta

@Yussef Muchas gracias a ambos por señalarlo, ahora me ha quedado claro y lo he agregado a la respuesta.
